# Error in SSIS when trying to move package from .txt to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm trying to move files from `.txt` to SQL Server and got these errors

> [OLE DB Destination [35]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
>
> An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Invalid character value for cast specification".
>
> An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Invalid character value for cast specification".
>
> [OLE DB Destination [35]] Error: There was an error with OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input].Columns[effdate] on OLE DB Destination.Inputs[OLE DB Destination Input]. The column status returned was: "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".

Comment: That's a pretty simple error: you are trying to take a column from your text file and put it into a SQL value, but somewhere along the way you have defined the data type incorrectly.  Anything anyone says beyond that in response to this question is going to be an educated guess, since you have nowhere near enough information for us to provide meaningful help.

Comment: Now, my educated guess:  either the `effdate` is formatted in a way that your package can't recognize as a date, or the column contains some value that isn't supposed to be there, or the date falls outside of the range accepted by the target SQL data type (e.g., you're trying to insert a 12/31/1899 into a SMALLDATETIME).

Comment: If you want more help, you're going to need to edit more details into your question: sample data, data types, and screenshots would be an excellent start.

Comment: thanks a lot @AHiggins and I am going to attach screenshots right now :)

Comment: thanks a lot for quick response guys :)

Comment: Were you able to resolve your problem?

Comment: yes!! I gave the date as 01012014 in .txt file which should be given as 01/01/2014 and was able to resolve it. Thankyou